# How can I insert a new markup element after 4 posts automatically?

Tags: posts, wp-query

How can I insert a new row query after 4 col-ms-4 automatically?

```
<section class="container" id="szolgaltatasok">
       <div class="row" id="szolgaltatasok">
        <?php
                $custom_query = new WP_Query('cat=-1'); // Kizárt kategória
                while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="col-md-4 portfolio-item" <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
                            <div class="szolgaltas-bg">
                                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                    the_post_thumbnail( 'la-dolce-vallata-blog' );} ?> 
                                <div class="szolgaltas-padding">
                                    <h3 id="h3-padding"><a id="szolgaltatasok" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>  
                                    <?php
                                    echo "<p>";
                                    $content = get_the_content();
                                    echo substr(strip_tags($content), 0, 123);
                                    echo "...</p>";
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                        </div>        
                <?php endwhile; ?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query
        ?>    
       </div>    
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by accessing `WP_Query` class [properties](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Properties), available while in the loop, like `$current_post` (index of the current post), `$post_count` (number of posts displayed), `$found_posts` (total number of posts matching query).

By using `$current_post`, `$post_count` and PHP [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), like shown below:

```
<?php if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();  
  $i = $custom_query->current_post;  
  $c = $custom_query->post_count;
  if ( $i % 4 == 0 ) {
    // happening for $i being 0, 4, 8 and so on
    echo '<div class="row">';
  } ?>

// single post markup

<?php if ( $i % 4 == 3 || $i == ( $c - 1 ) ) {
  // happening for $i being 3, 7, 11 and so on
  // OR condition in case the last one is not a multiple of 4
  echo '</div>';
}
endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Comment: Could you provde an example of how these properties could be used to solve the original question?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Sure, done.